# Не работает поиск в файле. PHP

Tags: php

**html**

```
 <form action="check.php" class="login-form" method="post">
   <input name="login" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
   ...
 </form>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
...
$user = "admin/".$login.".txt";
echo file($user)[0];
?>
```

Выдаёт ошибку -

*Warning: file(admin/.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...*

Я думал что может *$login* не работает, но там же изменив последнюю строку на

```
echo $login;
```

Он содержал то что нужно. Почему тогда ссылка не складывается?

Comment: Используйте полный путь к файлу

Comment: echo "admin/".$login.".txt";?

Comment: @wnull я проверял, и изменял переменную на нужное слово. Всё работало.

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov Ещё в моем посте было ясно что просто линк не делается. А из того что ты написал получилось - admin/.txt.

Comment: @AndrewKO322 `var_dump($_POST);` что даёт?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov array(0) { }

Comment: Он не может быть пустым, вы же отправляете форму ... там должны быть данные